# find hour or minute difference between 2 java.sql.Timestamps?

Tags: java

I store a `java.sql.Timestamp` in a *postgresql* database as *Timestamp* data type and I want to find out the difference in minutes or hours from the one stored in the DB to the current *timestamp*. What is the best way about doing this? are there built in methods for it or do I have to convert it to long or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two Java java.sql.Timestamps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582278/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-java-java-sql-timestamps)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ended using this, just want to post it for others if they search for it.

```
public static long compareTwoTimeStamps(java.sql.Timestamp currentTime, java.sql.Timestamp oldTime)
{
    long milliseconds1 = oldTime.getTime();
  long milliseconds2 = currentTime.getTime();

  long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
  long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
  long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
  long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
  long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    return diffMinutes;
}
```

Comment: You're The Best!

Comment: great solution Arya!

Comment: I have added an alternative answer which is much more elegant below using the methods of `ChronoUnit`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function to convert the DATETIME into the value in Hour, minutes and seconds.
And if you are not sure of which value is bigger then use the ABS function.

Answer (score 0):

For date add/remove this is my generic function :

```
public static Date addRemoveAmountsFromDate(Date date, int field, int amount) {
    Calendar tempCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    tempCalendar.setTime(date);
    tempCalendar.add(field, amount);

    return tempCalendar.getTime();
}
```

example for "field" : Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.MINUTE

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
Date.compareTo(Date)
```

You have to convert java.sql.Timestamps to Date first.

Comment: OP wants to find time elapsed till now in the form of hours and minutes but not if the dates are equal, before or after.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 0):

`date_part` function can give you `hours` or as the interest may be but, it is a kind of `substr` and hence can't rely on it. You need to convert your `timestamp` value into `unix_timestamp` and `extract` *total* elapsed number of hours, minutes or whatever relevant since your `timestamp` till `current_timestamp`.

**Example**:

```
select age( now(), timestamp '2010-11-12 13:14:15' );  
//results the interval to be "*1 year 6 mons 2 days 04:39:36.093*"  

select date_part( 'hours', age( now(), timestamp '2010-03-10 02:03:04' ) );  
// results *4* which is not correct.
```

Correct value of hours or others can be calculated after finding total number of seconds elapsed since 1970. This can be achieved using `epoch` with `extract` function.
`epoch` returns total number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00-00`. And, you know, we can convert it into hours by dividing it with 3600.

**Using `epoch` with `extract`**:

```
select
  EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM current_timestamp - timestamp '2010-11-12 13:14:15' ) as total_seconds,
  EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM current_timestamp - timestamp '2010-11-12 13:14:15' ) / 3600 as total_hours;  
  ROUND(  
         EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM current_timestamp - timestamp '2010-11-12 13:14:15' ) / 3600  
       ) as total_hours_rounded;
```

// results:

```
----------------+--------------+-----------------------  
| total_seconds | total_hours  | total_hours_rounded  |  
| --------------+--------------+----------------------|  
| 47452282.218  | 13181.189505 | 13181                |  
----------------+--------------+-----------------------
```

Similarly, we can extract other required values and use as required.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, It is extremely accurate :

```
    long diff = end - start;

    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    long remain = diff % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    long diffHours = remain / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    remain = remain % (60 * 60 * 1000);

    long diffMinutes = remain / (60 * 1000);
    remain = remain % (60 * 1000);

    long diffSeconds = remain / (1000);

    System.out.println("days : " + diffDays);
    System.out.println("hours : " + diffHours);
    System.out.println("minutes : " + diffMinutes);
    System.out.println("secs: " + diffSeconds2);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this is pretty ancient and it came up when I was searching for an elegant solution.

There is a much nicer way to do this without having to faff with millisecond conversions:

```
long totalHours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(startTime.toInstant(), endTime.toInstant());
long totalMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startTime.toInstant(), endTime.toInstant());
long totalSeconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(startTime.toInstant(), endTime.toInstant());
```

And a bunch of others `MILLIS`, `YEARS`, `DAYS`, `HALF_DAYS`, `DECADES`, `CENTURIES` and more!

Only thing I'm not sure about is if these longer units account for leap years and you may need to apply some changes if you want to account for time zones and DST.

Enjoy.