# How to calculate the difference in minutes between two timeStamp ( with different days)?

Tags: java, android, time, timestamp

I'm trying to calculate a difference in minutes between two java TimeStamps when I write: 
Timestamp `t1,t2;`

`t2.getTime()-t1.getTime();`
it returns only the difference between the two times and 
I need the difference the whole times (including days)

Comment: That sounds unlikely - what are the values of `t1.getTime()` and `t2.getTime()` in this case?

Comment: for example : 
02/24/2019 13:58:00
02/25/2019 12:58:00
the differnce is :1380 min

Comment: Right, and that's correct - 1380 minutes is 23 hours, which is the difference between those two values. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: I didn’t get what you were after, sorry. Do you want minutes, do you want days, what do you want? Please explain more clearly.

Comment: Consider adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project so that you can avoid the old, poorly designed and confusing `Timestamp` class and use for example `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between` or the `Duration` class. The modern API is so much nicer to work with, and I’m convinced that it more directly offers the functionality you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find total hours between two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003521/find-total-hours-between-two-dates) and/or [find hour or minute difference between 2 java.sql.Timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578674/find-hour-or-minute-difference-between-2-java-sql-timestamps)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
long difftime = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime();
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `java.sql.Timestamp`, the code below seems to work just fine:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

class Scratch {

    public static final long MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
    public static final long SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
    public static final long HOURS_PER_DAY = 24;
    public static final long MILLIS_PER_SECOND = 1000L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long oneDayPlusFiveMinutesInMillis = (MILLIS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE) * ( 5 + MINUTES_PER_HOUR * HOURS_PER_DAY);
        Timestamp t0 = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Timestamp t1 = new Timestamp(t0.getTime() + oneDayPlusFiveMinutesInMillis);
        long diff = (t1.getTime() - t0.getTime()) / (MILLIS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);
        System.out.println("t1 - t0 = " + diff + " minutes");
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
t1 - t0 = 1445 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between 2 timestamps gives milliseconds. Apply Maths afterwards:

```
// get time difference in seconds
long milliseconds = timestamp2.getTime() - timestamp1.getTime();
int seconds = (int) milliseconds / 1000;

// calculate hours minutes and seconds
int hours = seconds / 3600;
int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
seconds = (seconds % 3600) % 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Timestamp t1 = new Timestamp(new Date("04/26/2019 20:32:49").getTime());
    Timestamp t2 = new Timestamp(new Date("04/27/2019 19:32:49").getTime());

    long diff = t2.getTime() - t1.getTime();

    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    long diffTotMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);

    System.out.println("Days: " + diffDays + " \nTime: " + diffHours + ":" + diffMinutes + ":" + diffSeconds);
    System.out.println("Total Minutes: " + diffTotMinutes);
```

Out Put:

```
Days: 0 
Time: 23:0:0
Total Minutes: 1380
```

Comment: what if t2 == "04/27/2019 19:32:49"

Comment: `Days: 0 
Time: 23:0:0`