# Calculate Year, Month, Day Difference Between Timestamps

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two Java java.sql.Timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582278/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-java-java-sql-timestamps)

How do you calculate how many years/months/days (don't really need time) between two timestamps that you've acquired from an SQL in Java?

Below is a snippet of a code I'm using:

```
query = "SELECT bc.periodbeginningdate " +
            "FROM cus_billingcontract bc " +
            "WHERE cus_billingcontract_id = " + recordID;
Timestamp bDate = DB.getSQLValueTS(null, query);

query = "SELECT bc.periodenddate " +
            "FROM cus_billingcontract bc " +
            "WHERE cus_billingcontract_id = " + recordID;
Timestamp eDate = DB.getSQLValueTS(null, query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the timetamps to `long`s by using `getTime()`: see here for lots of info:

[How to calculate the difference between two Java java.sql.Timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582278/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-java-java-sql-timestamps?rq=1)

Then, with the `long` values, you can use the JodaTime libraries to easily access months differences.

See here:

[How to calculate difference ONLY in months using Java's Joda API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460701/how-to-calculate-difference-only-in-months-using-javas-joda-api)